# How to get auto selected same numeric option in a second select as that selected in first select?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, select

New to Bootstrap and JavaScript.

```
<select id="list1" name="list1" class="form-control" required/>
<?php
for ($h = 1; $h <= 7; $h++) echo "<option value='$h'>$h</option>";
?>
</select>


<select id="list2" name="list2" class="form-control" required/>
<?php
for ($h = 1; $h <= 7; $h++) echo "<option value='$h'>$h</option>";
?>
</select>
```

I have 2 selects, with option values 1-7 in each.
When a user selects a number in list1, I want the same number auto selected in list2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) property of `HTMLSelectElement`:

```js
const firstList = document.getElementById('list1');
const secondList = document.getElementById('list2');
firstList.addEventListener('change', () => {
  secondList.selectedIndex = firstList.selectedIndex;
});
```

```html
<select id="list1" name="list1" class="form-control" required>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>


<select id="list2" name="list2" class="form-control" required>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
```